# Start Rserve instance with SSL/TLS?

Tags: r, ssl, openssl, rserve

I am in a Windows environment, trying to start an instance of Rserve with TLS/SSL encryption using a config file with the following settings:

```
tls.key Rserve.key
tls.cert Rserve.cert
tls.port 4902
qap disable
```

When I build my Rserve instance, I get the following error:

```
WARNING: useplain=no, but this Rserve has no crypt support!
Set useplain=yes or compile with crypt support (if your system supports crypt).
```

The solution seems to be to compile Rserve with some OpenSSL option enabled, but I can't find any documentation to do so anywhere. I originally used CRAN to install Rserve. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to build Rserve with TSL support on Windows with the next steps:

- All build tools (make, cmake, automake, perl, python, gcc, R, etc.) are from 32-bit CygWin
- openssl and other libraries needed to build Rserve are also from CygWin and were installed with sources
- I had to uninstall Active Perl, Active Python but I believe it would be enough just make sure perl, python, make and other tools first found in CygWin binaries' folder
- You may need to modify some code (e.g. remove strnstr function and modify JDK version) to build tar.gz